# Very particular limsup of an integral

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Maybe its a very hard problem, but does someone know if exists a positive real function $g(x)$ such that:
$\displaystyle \limsup_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\displaystyle \int_{x}^{+\infty} \frac{W(t)}{t^{2}}dt}{g(x)} >1$, where $W(t)=\pi(t)-li(t)$, ?

Answer (score 5):

The general approach would be the following: First express $W$ using roots of $\zeta$. Then show that everything converges so well that you can interchange the sum over zeros with the integral over $t$ to get an explicit formula for $\int_x^\infty\frac{W(t)}{t^2}\;dt$. Finally use Turans power sum method to show that this integral becomes large and positive infinitely often. This strategy is well explained in Turan's book "A new method in analysis with applications".

The details become messy because the explicit formula will involve expressions of the form $\mathrm{li}(x^\rho)$, which you have to approximate before you apply general theorems. As an alternative you could first consider the integral $\int_x^\infty\frac{\tilde{W}(t)}{t^2}\;dt$, where $\tilde{W}=\Psi(x)-x$. In this case the explicit formula contains only terms of the form $\frac{x^\rho}{\rho}$, which are much easier to handle. Then you need some approximation to show that the existence of large positive values of the integral for $\tilde{W}$ implies the existence of large positive values of the integral for $W$.

Comment: I proved for myself without success...so can you give me more details about your idea? in particular, I don't know how to estimate the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho-1}}{\rho(\rho-1)}$ in order to construct my function g(x); otherwise can you give me some references in which I could see some examples of this method?

Comment: The standard reference is Turan's book. Another good example is "Oscillatory properties of the remainder term of the prime number formula" by Pintz, which appeared in Studies in pure mathematics to the memory of Paul Turan, Akademiai Kiado, Budapest. Most of these works were done before the internet, and are not part of standard analytic number theory classes, so the only web resource I found was an article by Revesz http://www.renyi.hu/~revesz/actaarithmetica.pdf , which deals with quite general oscillation questions.